# How to get the tag of an image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio

I would like to know if there is a quick way to get the tag of an image file using C#?

[image: What I mean about tags]

I'd like to get the tag, then make a string in my program equal to that tag.

Any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: That is not the tag of an image (as in: part of the image) - this is a normal file system property. Nothing image specific at all.

Comment: If you want to be get image related data you may want to search SO for `[exif] and [.net]`. Some of the magic numbers for EXIF properties may be found [here](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf).